# Is There a Range Based case-Like Control Structure

Tags: c++, events, switch-statement, range, control-structure

Say at run-time I establish some *events* with occurrence times. Now I have certain **entities** in the system and I need to establish which **entities** were impacted by these *events*.

So as an example say that I have:

- **Entity1** intialized at time 1
- *EventRed* occurs at time 3
- **Entity2** initialized at time 8
- *EventBlue* occurs at time 9
- *EventYellow* occurs at time 11
- **Entity3** initialized at time 13

This should result in:

- **Entity1** is white
- **Entity2** is green
- **Entity3** is black

I want a `case`-like control structure to do this which supports fall through and who's cases are evaluated as "greater than or equal to this value". I'd like syntax like this:

```
for(auto& i : Entity) {
    ?switch(i.GetInitializedTime()) {
    ?case(Red.GetOccuranceTime()):
        i.AddRed();
    ?case(Blue.GetOccranceTime()):
        i.AddBlue();
    ?case(Yellow.GetOccuranceTime()):
        i.AddYellow();
    }
}
```

Is there a control structure like this or do I have to juggle all the if statements?

Comment: I was pretty baffled when I saw this syntax first time: `case 0x20 ... 0xFF:`, but I'm not sure if its a GCC specific extension.

Comment: For what you require in your example, that's not possible, because the case label jump marks need to be known at compile time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It is an extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

Comment: @Christian THX for the enlightenment.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Arg, this is the control structure I want! But I can't seem to find anything about this being supported in Visual Studio :( Maybe I could dig up implementation code and replicate...

Comment: @JonathanMee: There is no "implementation code" to replicate, unless you want to write it in assembler...

Comment: @ChristianHackl That seems like a bad plan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the *event* times are not known at design time, even [gcc's range based case statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) are [not viable solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040490/is-there-a-range-based-case-like-control-structure?noredirect=1#comment53901780_33040490). As such the best solution is to contain the *events* in a [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Because in the original question an *event* was only a number that caused a specific method to be called on the `entity`, this process can be simplified by eleminating the *event* object; having the `map` use the number which would have been contained by the *event* look up the `entity` method it would have called. For example: `map<int, function<void(entity&)>> events` can be populated by:

```
events[3] = mem_fn(&entity::AddRed);
evnets[9] = mem_fn(&entity::AddBlue);
events[11] = mem_fn(&entity::AddYellow);
```

Once `events` has been populated, the `case` statement can be replaced with iterating through `events`, beginning at `entity i`'s `GetInitializedTime()`:

```
for(auto j = events.upper_bound(i.GetInitializedTime()); j != events.end(); ++j) {
    j->second(i);
}
```

[`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) is used to find the beginning iterator this since it:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is greater than key

[This live example](http://ideone.com/u0rewz) uses the functionality above, but in order to showcase that it uses bitwise array indexing. When indexing `entity::colorArray` the least significant bit is a boolean for whether blue has been added, the middle bit is yellow, and the most significant bit is red.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that is even remotely like what you need. You'll have to write your own class for this. Practically speaking, it looks like a sorted vector of `<time, function>` pairs.

Even the GCC "range extension" of the switch statement takes fixed ranges.